# Why does the alt or title tags don't work in e-mails?

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I have a problem with e-mail templates. I use in most of my e-mailtemplates images. The problem with images in e-mails is that they need to be downloaded before showing up. I always uses ALT- and TITLE tags to define what images it is.

I found this problem in all of the Outlook clients. When you're NOT downloading the images the tags wont appear. Is there any fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The text you see when the images are not loaded in outlook is a security feature and there are no walk arounds for it.

> Blocking pictures can help protect your computer. Microsoft Outlook is
>   configured by default to block automatic picture downloads from the
>   Internet. You can, however, unblock pictures that you think are safe
>   to download.
>
> Advantages of blocking automatic picture downloads include:
>
> 1. Helping you avoid viewing potentially offensive material (when external content is linked to the message).
> 2. Helping to keep malicious code from damaging the data on your computer.
> 3. Allowing you to decide—especially if you're on a low-bandwidth connection—whether a particular image warrants the time and bandwidth
>      required for downloading.

You can read more about it on [Microsoft's site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Block-or-unblock-automatic-picture-downloads-in-email-messages-15e08854-6808-49b1-9a0a-50b81f2d617a).

Hope thats what you were looking for.